# Behavior of Natural Abundance and Mass Spec Ratios

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry, isotope

The presence of sulfur in a mass spec is 96% and 4%. I believe this to be because the natural occurrence of sulfur isotopes are within these proportions.

However, chlorine behaves in a 66%/33% ratio in mass spec, but the most abundance isotopes of chlorine are 75%/25%. Why is this so?

Comment: See also [chemguide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/masspec/elements.html) mentioning 3:1 atomic ions and 9:6:1 molecular ions, based on [webbook.nist.gov](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/)

Comment: What sort of compounds are you using ?

Comment: Or in more general terms: ratio (66:33 relative to each other) vs percent (75% and 25% relative to their sum).

Comment: Side note: isotopic distributions may vary both along time and place.  This is why IUPAC's atomic weight for Li seems to be less and less precise today and compared to other elements. [Isotopic fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_signature) are used in geology not only to tell age, but origin of the samples ([example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4996820/)) e.g.for the analysis of [gemstones](https://doi.org/10.2113/gselements.1.2.79) as well as in forensics ([example](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/20961790.2018.1549527)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably mixing [*natural* abundance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_abundance) (NA) and *relative* abundance (RA).
In mass spectrometry RA is a more valuable parameter as it can be directly obtained as the $y$-coordinate of a plotted mass spectra: the most abundant ion (isotope) corresponds to the base peak, which is always $100\%.$
In other words, RA reflect isotope *ratio*, not NA.
For the isotopes of the elements RAs can easily be derived from NAs via normalization; however, the problem of finding RAs of the various isotopic *molecular* species is a bit less trivial [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed039p335)].

The following table contains compiled data for NAs [2, p. 1-12] and RAs [3, p. 89] for both elements you've mentioned:

$$
\newcommand{\d}[2]{#1.&\hspace{-1em}#2}
\begin{array}{lllrlrlr}
\hline
Z & \text{Isotope} & & &\text{Mass}/\pu{u} & \text{NA}&\hspace{-1em}/\% & \text{RA}&\hspace{-1em}/\%\\
\hline
16 & \ce{^{32}S} & \ce{[E]}      & \d{31}{9720711744(14)} & \d{94}{99(26)} & \d{100}{000} &\hspace{-1em} \\
   & \ce{^{33}S} & \ce{[E + 1]}  & \d{32}{9714589098(15)} & \d{0}{75(2)}   & \d{0}{789} \\
   & \ce{^{34}S} & \ce{[E + 2]}  & \d{33}{96786700(5)}    & \d{4}{25(24)}  & \d{4}{433} \\
\hline
17 & \ce{^{35}Cl} & \ce{[E]}     & \d{34}{96885268(4)} & \d{75}{76(10)}    & \d{100}{000} \\
   & \ce{^{37}Cl} & \ce{[E + 2]} & \d{36}{96590260(6)} & \d{24}{24(10)}    & \d{32}{399} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

#### References

1. Margrave, J. L.; Polansky, R. B. Relative Abundance Calculations for Isotopic Molecular Species. *J. Chem. Educ.* **1962**, 39 (7), 335. DOI: [10.1021/ed039p335](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed039p335).
2. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data*, 97th ed.; Taylor & Francis Group (CRC Press): Boca Raton, FL, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.
3. Gross, J. H. *Mass Spectrometry: A Textbook*, 3rd ed.; Springer International Publishing: Cham, Switzerland, **2017**. ISBN 978-3-319-54397-0.

Comment: So 66% / 33% is wrong, it should be 100% / 33% or 75% / 25% if you round a bit. For sulfur with the low abundance of S-34, ratio or fraction are similar, at about 4%.